# How can my database be improved?

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to store news articles. I have the three following tables:

categories (**category_id**, category_name)

websites (**website_id**, website_name, website_url)

articles (**article_id**, *website_id*, *category_id*, article_author, article_pubdate, article_title, article_description, article_content)

Key: **primary key**, *foreign key*

Can this be improved upon? Is it in 3NF?

Comment: At the very least, I would add an `article_categories` table (consisting of _article_id_ and _category_id_ (and remove _category_id_ from the `articles` table)) so that an article can be in more than one category. Possibly the same with websites, in case an article can appear on more than one site.

Comment: @beercodebeer thank you. Would `article_id, category_id` be a composite key?

Comment: No, it would be a link table with just the two foreign keys, to `articles` and `categories`.

Comment: But in the article_categories table, yes it should be a composite PK to avoid duplication of the same records

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll probably want a many-to-many relationship between articles and categories (this requires another table)
2. Don't prefix column names with `tablename_` (though this is fine for the `id` columns)
3. Unique indexes on category name, website name, url